# How to stay logged in permanently in asp classic

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

I'm trying to implement the logic Facebook does for its website in my ASP classic application. When you enter facebook for the first time and enter you email and password, when you close the browser and enter facebook.com it redirect you to the hompage because it has already stored your session. I've increased the session timeout to over 50000 minutes but when I start active for 20 minutes and close the browser and re open the website again, it tell me to enter my username and password again.

So how do I store my session variables to still maintain it even if I close the browser and opens it again?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not use session cookies, they actually use REAL cookies with long expire dates to keep you signed in.  What you want to do is store you sessions in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the information in a real cookie (a secure cookie). If the cookie is set, try to relogin the user again. You have to read the cookie at the beginning of every page you load.

Comment: can you give me a sample script?